# ShellExecuteA cannot execute '.exe' in Python (with. ctypes ShellExecuteA)

Tags: python, ctypes, shell32

I have compiled below code but cannot execute the "PPP.exe".

'.exe' file exists same directory with '.py' file.

Why cannot working(or "open") this code?? Please let me know.

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteA(0, 'open', "PPP.exe",  None, None, 1)
```

Comment: run this code on win10, Python 3.11 and VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ShellExecuteW`.  Your strings are Unicode strings and are passed as `wchar_t*` to C.

Alternatively, use byte strings with `ShellExecuteA`, e.g. `b'open'` and `b'PPP.exe'`.

If you fully define the arguments and return type (*always* recommended), then `ctypes` will type-check for you and return an error if the type is incorrect:

```py
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w

SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1

shell32 = ct.WinDLL('shell32')
shell32.ShellExecuteA.argtypes = w.HWND, w.LPCSTR, w.LPCSTR, w.LPCSTR, w.LPCSTR, w.INT
shell32.ShellExecuteA.restype = w.HINSTANCE
shell32.ShellExecuteW.argtypes = w.HWND, w.LPCWSTR, w.LPCWSTR, w.LPCWSTR, w.LPCWSTR, w.INT
shell32.ShellExecuteW.restype = w.HINSTANCE

# works
shell32.ShellExecuteA(None, b'open', b'cmd.exe', None, None, SW_SHOWNORMAL)

# works
shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, 'open', 'cmd.exe', None, None, SW_SHOWNORMAL)

# ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
shell32.ShellExecuteA(None, 'open', 'cmd.exe', None, None, SW_SHOWNORMAL)

# ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, b'open', b'cmd.exe', None, None, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
```

Comment: wow.. Exactly, because of VScode encdoding. I tried to "".encode('cp949'). 
I should have checked return code!  Thank you so much :)